# visual studio code: how can i launch a command to a new terminal from a command

Tags: cmd.exe, visual-studio-code, npm

I want to run two concurrent commands using `npm run` in visual studio code, each one in a separate terminal tab in vscode.
I tried doing this:

```
start 'command a' && start 'command b'
```

but that just opened them in two different cmd windows
I want them to open in a new terminal tab within vscode
Is there a way to do this?

I'm using windows 10 and running it from an npm script if it matters

Answer (score -1):

You can use Tasks https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks with dependencies to accomplish something like what you want.

However because of the limitations of tasks you cannot execute a dynamic number of terminals, which is why I'm also looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126949)